# Can we use step in Rust slice?

Tags: rust, slice

In python, we can get subarray in odd indexes like:

```
odd = array[1::2]
```

Can we do this in Rust, using simple syntax or any traits? like:

```
let vec = vec![1; 10];
let sli = &vec[0.2.10];
```

The above code cannot pass the compile.

Comment: the answer is no but your question show your lack of Rust knowledge, what you want to probably an iterator on the array that step see https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by

Comment: Too giant to step on the memory, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,Rust slicing syntax does not support.

you can achieve it by using the `.iter()` method with the `.enumerate()` and `.filter()` methods to create an iterator that only yields elements at odd indices. If you need the result to be a `Vec`, you can then collect this iterator into a `Vec`,

```
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let odd: Vec<_> = vec.iter()
                     .enumerate()
                     .filter(|&(i, _)| i % 2 != 0)
                     .map(|(_, e)| e)
                     .collect();
println!("{:?}", odd);
```

Note that the indices are 0-based, so this gives you elements at odd indices, which are the even elements of the original vector. If you want the elements at even indices, you can change `i % 2 != 0 to i % 2 == 0`.

Answer (score 8):

Rust doesn't have this Python feature. However, you can apply a step size to any iterator by using the [`.step_by()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.step_by) method.

```
let v: Vec<i32> = (0..10).step_by(2).collect();
assert_eq!(v, vec![0, 2, 4, 6, 8]);
```

However, note that the step size must be positive, unlike Python, where a negative step size means to walk the list backwards. To reverse an iterator in Rust, you can usually use [`.rev()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.rev).

```
let v2: Vec<i32> = v.into_iter().rev().collect();
assert_eq!(v2, vec![8, 6, 4, 2, 0]);
```

If you're using a tensor library, like [ndarray](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/), it'll have its own way of slicing with a step size, like [this ndarray macro](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/macro.s.html).

Answer (score 6):

No, a [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) is

> A dynamically-sized view into a **contiguous** sequence

You could collect references into the original slice into a `Vec` though:

```rust
let odd: Vec<&i32> = array.iter().step_by(2).collect();
```

But for many applications you don't even need to `collect` at all but can use the `Iterator` directly.